# «Экстра такси» — детский вопрос о названии передачи

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия, сокращения, слитно-раздельно-дефис

На канале ТВ-3 имеется [**реклама**](https://www.vokrug.tv/product/show/16914156641/) нового шоу.
Название представлено таким образом:
**«ЭКСТРА такси»** — новое мистическое шоу с Владом Череватым.

Есть и другие написания: *ЭКСТРА Такси, ЭКСТРА ТАКСИ, Экстра такси, Экстра Такси.*

Ребенок (11 лет) заинтересовался:
как же правильно назвать передачу — экстрасенсное или экстрасенсорное такси (экстраординарное, экстравагантное — такие прилагательные поначалу тоже рассматривались);
грамотно ли оформлено сокращение (прописные-строчные буквы; слитно, раздельно, через дефис)?
Обращаюсь за помощью.

Comment: Экстра = самый лучший. Или в этом шоу у «экстра» другое значение? http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0&all=x

Comment: Никак не грамотно, потому что экстра - это выходящий за рамки. В этом смысле сокращение экстрасенс(выходящий за рамки чувственного восприятия) - до экста, смысла не имеет. Потому что экстра-такси - выходящий за рамки такси, ну то есть бред. Поэтому берут и пишут слово экстра одними заглавными буквами, чтобы это было не слово, а черт знает что. Гипертекст мб какой. ЭКСТРА.

Comment: @Слава Конечно же, мы посмотрели значение "экстра" в словаре. Ну а  Влад Чреватый — участник шоу «Битва экстрасенсов», не гонщик, не таксист в обычной жизни, не товар высшего качества (если так можно о человеке). Вопрос поэтому — о написании, о сокращении — и возник собственно...

Comment: А почему не дефисное написание? Выглядит неграмотно, что бы оно ни означало. Иноязычный элемент в препозиции не пишется раздельно. Надо хотя бы местами переставить: Такси – сверху, а ЭКСТРА – внизу. Экстрасенсорный   https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/экстрасенсорный

Comment: Э-э... *Sharon*, Вы меня спрашиваете — почему? Мы сейчас совсем *не много* каналов смотрим на русском языке, поэтому, наверно, чаще и "заостряемся". Я засомневалась и не смогла ответить девочке на ее вопрос — "а как же надо?"

Comment: "Экстрасенсный" плоховато звучит, вообще его не встречал. "Экстрасенсорный" его затмило.

Comment: Плоховато звучит или не плоховато, но слово "экстрасенсный" зафиксировано в словарях. (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) Вопрос ведь не об этом.

Comment: Мы ориентируемся на звучание, когда делаем выбор. Это даже непосредственно по части стилистики (благозвучность фразы), про что вчера читал. Раз в словарях указано, что нет разницы, то понятно, что лучше выбрать. Хотя можно было бы предположить, что экстрасенсорный — обладающий экстрасенсорными способностями либо выраженный ими, а экстрасенсный — связанный с экстрасенсами.

Comment: Вам на заметку: значение приставка "экстра-" совпадает с этимологией слова "экстрасенс".

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за то, что где-то что-то совпадает. Но, пожалуйста, не надо больше никаких "на заметку". Хочется ведь получить правильный полноценный ответ, если нужно — и с этимологией, и с примерами, и с мнением плоховато-"хорошевато". Мы всё очень-очень внимательно прочитаем.

Comment: @oleedd
Миниатюра для вас: — Профессор, за что же мне неуд? Разве я плохо ответил на вопрос. — Да плоховато, знаете ли.  — Но ведь можно считать, что «хорошевато»  и поставить хотя бы удовлетворительно.

Comment: @Sharon А вас за ваши новаторства давно уже пора отчислить.

Comment: @oleedd Или арестовать (по Булгакову)...

Answer (score 1):

Влад Череватый — победитель конкурса экстрасенсов. Поэтому очевидно, что он использует слово "Экстра" как ассоциацию к шоу, в котором участвовал.

Поэтому "Такси экстрасенса", если хотите. Вот собственно описание шоу в качестве доказательства именно такой версии:

> Победитель "Битвы экстрасенсов" Влад Череватый сел за руль городского
> такси и подвозит случайных пассажиров. За время короткой поездки он
> расскажет о них то, что повергнет в шок и их самих, и зрителей.

https://tv3.ru/project/ekstra-taksi

Comment: Спасибо. А как все-таки надо писать "Экстра такси"?

Comment: Как угодно, это придуманное название передачи. Можете посмотреть, как они пишут по ссылке. Впрочем, я бы с ребенком смотрел что-то, что продвигает научный взгляд на мир, а не это. Но это мое частное мнение.

Comment: @SergZ. "Дык" мы и посмотрели, **как** эти названия пишутся (я же сама привела ссылку и примеры). Понятно, что это *придуманное название* (а каким оно еще может быть? Всё ведь придумано, кроме цитат). Как угодно — это, конечно, здорово. А как правильно? P. S. Никто пока ничего не смотрит (думаю, и не будет смотреть) — это реклама передачи, которую ребенок увидел и которая выйдет на экраны только в конце августа.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Как правильно записать?**

Нельзя нарушать правила письма, но нужно следовать семантике текста. Будем считать, что у нас **«такси экстрасенса».**

**Смотрим на афишу:** там позиционная запись, причем прописными буквами и разным  по величине шрифтом. Следовательно, это **две части** названия для передачи, а не одно слово.

Но нам-то надо записать его в строку. Есть вариант: **ЭКСТРА такси,** и он, пожалуй, будет лучшим. Действительно, прописными и строчными буквами обозначены **две части** названия, а не единое слово «экстра такси» (в котором нужно писать дефис в случае иноязычного элемента в препозиции).

Как вообще решаются задачи **с такой двойственностью?** «Похождения Чичикова, или Мёртвые души»? Но нет, не то — здесь взаимозаменяемость названий, а у нас две части названия.

**Вот учебник** с позиционным названием двух частей: **Синтаксис современного русского языка** (прописные буквы), а ниже — **Курс лекций** (строчные буквы). На выходном листе запись: Синтаксис современного русского языка : курс лекций.  Да,  **двоеточие с пробелами**, обозначающее границу. В общем, кто как выходит из этого положения.

Есть и **другие написания:** ЭКСТРА Такси, ЭКСТРА ТАКСИ, Экстра такси, Экстра Такси. Но все чем-то нехороши: то правила нарушают, то афише не соответствуют.

**2.  О прилагательных "экстрасенсный"  и "экстрасенсорный"**

**ЭКСТРАСЕНСОРНЫЙ**. Связанный со сверхчувственными способностями человека распознавать и лечить заболевания, психические расстройства и т.п. Э-ые способности. Э. дар.

**ЭКСТРАСЕНСНЫЙ**. =Экстрасенсорный. Э-ые способности.

По словарю видно, что основным прилагательным является ***экстрасенсорный***, для которого дано определение.

**Но почему так**? Сравним по словарю Ефремовой суффиксы ***Н*** и ***ОРН***. Там суффикс ***ОРН*** — это вариант суффикса ***Н***. Оба суффикса являются относительными, но *ОРН* присоединяется преимущественно к основе существительных — интернациональных терминов: ***рефлекторный, иллюзорный***.

Также отметим, что слово ***экстрасенсный*** неудобно для произношения ввиду стечения согласных ***НСН***.

С другой стороны, сочетание такси с обоими прилагательными **не очень благозвучно,** так что лучше им не пользоваться вообще. Пусть будет *ЭКСТРА такси* или  *Такси экстрасенса* (при свободном толковании названия).

Comment: Вы можете объяснить написание? А то у вас только "и он, пожалуй, будет лучшим".

Comment: @Sharon То есть все-таки *ЭКСТРА такси* нужно считать новаторством или редакторской вольностью? Ведь орфографическими правилами такое написание объяснить невозможно.

Comment: Это имя собственное, а там возможны условности. Фактически это экстра-такси, сокращение от "экстрасенсорное такси". Можно сравнить: яхт-клуб. Вольность в записи, где дефисное написание заменено позиционным.  А при записи в строку деление названия на две части обозначено прописными и строчными буквами. Другого варианта я не вижу. Можно также использовать двойное название: ЭКСТРА такси, или Такси экстрасенса.

Comment: Спасибо за интересный вопрос.